# Is there a way to have PHP convert sql results straight to JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm curious if I'll have to roll my own or if there's a pre-made PHP SQL library that I'm overlooking whereby I can pass in a sql select query and have it give me back a JSON object (or String) as a result.

In pseudo code what I want is this:

```
$startIndex = 0;
$myJSON = magicSqlToJSON("select first_name, last_name, phone,  (select count(id) from users) as total from users limit $startIndex, 2");
```

$myJSON is now:

```
{"users":[
   {"first_name":"Peter", "last_name":"O'Tool","phone":"1234567890","total":"100"},
   {"first_name":"Gary", "last_name":"Shandling","phone":"1234567890","total":"100"}
]}
```

I know it wouldn't take very long to write this myself, but I kind of figured that this is just too common a need that it wouldn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *single* function that exists natively in PHP

However, you could do this quite quickly using a combination of `mysqli_fetch_array()` (for example) and `json_encode()`. You'd likely have to tweak the parent format slightly (i.e. underneath "*users*")

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

PHP has the `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions for this purpose, but you would need to manually loop over your data with a `foreach` or similar.

### MySQL

You can make use of a User Defined Function such as [lib_mysqludf_json](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_json/index.php), which would allow you return a JSON array from a query like so:

```
select json_array(
           customer_id
       ,   first_name
       ,   last_name
       ,   last_update
       ) as customer
from   customer 
where  customer_id =1;
```

Yields this result:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| customer                                 |
+------------------------------------------+
| [1,"MARY","SMITH","2006-02-15 04:57:20"] |
+------------------------------------------+
```

There is also a `json_object` function in that UDF, which should give you a very close representation of the sample in your question.

Comment: that's cool, but the other answers seem to come closer to what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* direct function but yo can do something else :

The result are coming from an array so just call

json_encode(array); -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

On it and that's it

Example:

```
$query = "select first_name, last_name, phone,  (select count(id) from users) as total from users limit $startIndex, 2";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: fixed sorry i'm a bit tired :)

Answer (score 0):

Ill assume you use PDO

```
echo json_encode($pdo->exec($sql)->fetchAll());
```

otherwise, the general pattern is

```
$handle = execute_query($sql);
$rows = array();
while ($row = get_row_assoc($handle)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```